# Find all AD users who have an IdentityReference equal to S-1-5-32-554 Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As a security measure, I recently removed "Authenticated Users" from the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group. I ran a PowerShell script as a normal user to retrieve all users "createTimeStamp" attribute, and only a few users show a time stamp in the output. When I run it as a Domain Admin, ALL users show a time stamp in the output.

Further investigation showed that a user with the "IdentityReference" of "S-1-5-32-554", (Builtin\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group) will show the time stamp when the script is ran as a normal user. A user without that identity reference does not show the time stamp when the script is ran as a normal user. This leaves a handful of users AD Information vulnerable. Also, these users are not a member of the Builtin\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group, but some how this IdentityReference is still attached to them.

What I am looking for are two scripts
The first needs to retrieve all users who have an "IdentityReference" set as "S-1-5-32-554
The second is to remove this "IdentityReference" of "S-1-5-32-554 from every user listed in a .csv file, say NoMoreWin2kCompat.csv.

I've research extensively and found nothing here or elsewhere that helps me solve this issue.

The last PowerShell script that I tried was:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “ou=Active-Users,ou=Users-IF,dc=if,dc=com” | Select -expand IdentityReference |where-object {-like "*S-1-5-32-554*"}
```

This returned an empty report

@Gabriel Luci

Yep, that is the weird thing. I removed the "Authenticated Users" from the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group for security reasons, which is what this Identity Reference is pointing to. The reason for doing this is because with "Authenticated Users" from the Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group, (Pre-Win2k) anyone can query the AD and get all attributes about all users, including such things as the “PasswordNotRequired” flag. That would be a bad thing. So after removing this account and running the following PowerShell script as a normal user, I could still see these Object properties for some users, but not all users.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Property Created, createTimeStamp, whenCreated, Modified, modifyTimeStamp, whenChanged, LastLogonDate | Select-Object -Property Name, SAMAccountName, Created, createTimeStamp, whenCreated, Modified, modifyTimeStamp, whenChanged, LastLogonDate | export-csv C:\SomeFolder\SomeFilename.csv
```

When I ran the same script as an AD Admin, it returns these Object properties for all users.

Next I ran the following script on a single user account to try and find out why: ($UserName is defined as the user name in question)

```
(Get-ACL "AD:$((Get-ADUser $UserName).distinguishedname)").access  | Export-Csv -Path C:\SomeFolder\SomeFilename.csv
```

This returns the following information. This is not all the info, just one line of the relevant info.

```
ActiveDirectoryRights = ReadProperty
InheritanceType = None
ObjectType = 037088f8-0ae1-11d2-b422-00a0c968f939
InheritedObjectType = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags = ObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType = Allow
IdentityReference = S-1-5-32-554  <--(Builtin\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access Group) 
IsInherited = FALSE
InheritanceFlags = None
PropagationFlags = None
```

I have manually added this user to the Pre-Win2k group, replicated to all DC's then manually removed this user from that group, re-ran the above code. It returned the same results.

I am at a loss as how to query the AD to find all users who are still flagged as being a part of this group. Then I'll need to remove these ACL's from a list of these employees.

Hopefully this is not to lengthy but describes the issue I am having a bit better.

@An-dir,
Thanks for the pointers. Your statement of "Some protected accounts and former admin accounts may be protected by disabled inheritance (and may have/had AdminCount=1) and might have set custom security settings" was right on target. All of the accounts affected either do have or did have AdminCount=1 set on them. It is these accounts that are allowing to much information to be read from a Powershell query like the one I listed above.

So now the million dollar question is, how do I go about fixing this issue? How do I tell the Active Directory not to return the full range of information for these user accounts when queried from a normal "Domain User" account?

I still feel this is fallout from removing the "Everyone" account from the "
PreWin2k" group, so there must be some way to rectify the issue.

Comment: Very little code for the requirements you have in your question. Your report is empty because there is no such attribute on User objects with name `IdentityReference` you can start by getting the `nTSecurityDescriptor` attribute and from there filter `where-object { $_.nTSecurityDescriptor ... `

Comment: [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids#:~:text=A%20local%20group%20that%20exists%20only%20on%20systems%20running%20Windows%202000%20Server.%20For%20more%20information%2C) describes that SID as a local group on the server. So you won't find it referenced in AD anywhere. It sounds like it's a group on the domain controller itself.

Comment: Your `Where-Object` clause is missing the part to compare for the `-like` operator and you probably mean to compare the users `SID` property instead of `IdentityReference`

Comment: @BiGBaG as already noted in my answer your solution is in the permissions of `CN=AdminSDHolder,CN=System,DC=<yourdomain>,DC=<tld>` These permissions differ the the default user, permissions, but also might have too much permissions due to a problem that came offen in the past when Exchange was updated and active sync devices could not be configured.

Comment: @An-dir Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It took a bit more research into AdminSDHolder permisions, but I finally got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the list requested you could do the following Powershell script

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties nTSecurityDescriptor | where {-not $($list = $_.nTSecurityDescriptor.access.IdentityReference.Value; $list -contains "S-1-5-32-554" -or $list -contains "Builtin\Pre-Windows 2000 compatible access" -or $List -contains "VORDEFINIERT\Prä-Windows 2000 kompatibler Zugriff")}
```

Take a look here:
[image: Security settings example]

It are permissions that are inherited by default, if inheritance is on! Some protected accounts and former admin accounts may be protected by disabled inheritance (and may have/had `AdminCount=1`) and might have set custom security settings. These are "stamped" onto the protected accounts using the permissions from `CN=AdminSDHolder,CN=System,DC=<yourdomain>,DC=<tld>`.
Some more users (like MSOL_*) have special permissions when created, so be cautious when changing your Users.

More about Pre-Windows 2000 compatible access group:
https://www.semperis.com/blog/security-risks-pre-windows-2000-compatibility-windows-2022/